# Why socketio working with polling but not with websocket over kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, socket.io, fastapi

Im trying to add websocket to my web app that run on kubernetes.
Im using python with fastapi as server and next.js as client and trying to add websocket with fastapi-socketio and socketio.

The frontend code:(I've changed it to wss when deployed to k8s..)

```
Const socket = io('ws://localhost:8000', {
  path: "/ws",
  transports: ['websocket'],
  retries: 1,
  reconnection: false,
});
```

The backend MySocketClass.py(The cors list is empty because I allowed all origin at the app.py with the recommended way to do so with fastapi, when I specified here again the origin it caused an error of multiple headers)

```
from fastapi_socketio import SocketManager

Class MySocketManager:
  sm_clients = {}
  def __init__(self, app, mount_route):
    self.sm = SocketManager(app=app, mount_location=mount_route, socketio_path="", cors_allowed_origin=[])
...
```

The backend code app.py:

```
app = FastApi()
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event:
  app.state.socketClass = MySocketManager(app=app, mount_route="/ws")
```

Locally on my computer I'm able to establish connection but when deploying to k8s i got an error "connection failed". If I try to connect with polling instead of websocket as transportation method it works over k8s.

Any suggestions how to fix it?

Ive been trying all the recommended annotations and configuration for the ingress as well for my backend pod and nothing works.

Also ive tried to downgrade the versions to matching one as the documentation of socketio says.

Furthermore, ive changed the service to NodePort for debugging and tried to connect from the frontend that run locally but in both cases (as NodePort and as ClusterIp) i don't see any log at the backend when trying to connect with websocket

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, always work with venv guys!
If somone encounter the same issue, for me adding 'websocket' to the requirements file fix the problem.(fastapi-socketio doesn't include this library within it)